# HTML video element width - 100%

Tags: html, css

What is the recommended/best way to set a video tag's width?

```
<video width="100%" ...></video>
```

Or using CSS:

```
video {
    width: 100%
}
```

I would usually go the CSS route 100% of the time, but setting widths in elements like the `canvas` can be problematic.

Comment: Go with the CSS approach if you can. It's more flexible.

Comment: try this <video style="width:100%" ...> </video>

Comment: you have missed `;` in your css. please correct it

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS is better
because it improves code readability

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for making responsive video element, then you need to wrap video inside a div with width 100%.

Here it goes:

```
div.video {
max-width:100%;
height:auto;
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}
.video {
width: /* More than element */;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the both the following link

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_width_height
There is no difference it makes.

**1. Inline**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="100%" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
 
</body>
</html>
```

**2. CSS**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style> video{width  : 100%; }</style>
<video height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Better use the `css`.

It is good to style externally, not inline..

**CSS**

```
video {
 width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to make your video in full screen

```
video {
    width: 100%    !important;
    height: auto   !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a responsive html5 video tag you can go with this simple approach:

html

```
<video width="640" height="264" data-setup="{}" preload="auto" controls="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" id="video_1">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="video/src.mp4"></source>
    <source type="video/webm" src="video/src.webm"></source>
    <source type="video/ogg" src="video/src.ogv"></source>
    <p class="vjs-no-js">To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that <a target="_blank" href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/">supports HTML5 video</a></p>
</video>
```

width and height attributes are a simple aspect ratio. Override these values using css to keep your code as maintainable as possible.

css

```
video {
    height: auto !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Now your video will resize according to your container width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript to dynamically set the height to 100% of the window and then center it using a negative left margin based on the ratio of video width to window width.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/RfV5C/43/)

```
var $video  = $('video'),
    $window = $(window); 

$(window).resize(function(){
    var height = $window.height();
    $video.css('height', height);

    var videoWidth = $video.width(),
        windowWidth = $window.width(),
    marginLeftAdjust =   (windowWidth - videoWidth) / 2;

    $video.css({
        'height': height, 
        'marginLeft' : marginLeftAdjust
    });
}).resize();
```

Comment: This task does not require the usage of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should be as simple as setting the min-height and min-width to 100%. So for example:

```
#video {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```

This may need to be adjusted for responsiveness.

Check out this[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/u9ncpyfu/6/)